# How to increase performance with joins to create VIEW from Wordpress wp_usermeta

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, metadata, wordpress, query-performance

After a lot of searching, I finally was able to create a SQL Query to retrive Wordpress User Meta Data. Now the problem is, the performance is so bad it doesn't even show me a result after 30 min.

Wordpress stores data in 3 columns: `user_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`. 
So each entry gets one row. 
What I need is one row per user, with each `meta_key` as its own column.

In other words, I have this:

```
user_id | meta_key | meta_value
       1|Name      |David
       1|Lastname  |Brown
```

But I need this:

```
user_id|Name |Lastname
      1|David|Brown
```

My approch on this is:

```
select m1.user_id, m1.meta_value as Vorname_M, m2.meta_value as Nachname_M,m3.meta_value as Adresse_M
from wp_usermeta m1
join wp_usermeta m2 on (m1.user_id = m2.user_id and m2.meta_key =  'nachname')
join wp_usermeta m3 on (m2.user_id = m3.user_id and m3.meta_key = 'adress')
where m1.meta_key = 'vorname'
```

With 5 joins it still works, but takes already 4 sec. All in all there are actually 17 joins, and at this point it doesnt show me anything.

I am running the query in phpMyAdmin, and would like to create a VIEW out of the result.

Now the actual question is: How can I increase the perfomance on my query, or how to rewrite it? I am givng my best, but I am actually a starter in SQL.

MySql version: 5.5

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of many questions on the site. [This one] looks spot on for your problem. The first answer listed (at this point) is what you've already tried; the second would group the rows by user_id, and take the `MAX` ( or `MIN`) value of the rows with each of the labels; that may be faster. You may also have to consider adding an appropriate index (like on `user_id` and `meta_key`) if none exists today; I would hope one *does* exit, but you never know. You may need to provide an EXPLAIN ANALYZE of the query, so people can see where it gets bogged down.

Comment: Well, i actaully didnt know what pivot rows is, so wouldnt search for it. And yes, its kinda  a duplicate of many questions, and i viewed a lot of them. Just, it confuses me a lot, and most questions and/or answers couldn't make any sense for me.I am actually not the type who has a question and imediatly spams all platforms for answers. I tried to figure it out for 20h over 2 days, and sadly was just not able to get it done. I am sorry i pulled up this question again, as i saw that it is similar asked many times, not only on this platform. But i am still very thankful i got the help i needed.

Comment: I looked up the Link you posted first now. Yeah, pivoting rows seems to be exactly what i do, i really wished i had found that post, or any similar.

Comment: Sorry - meant to include the link in the second post as well (and too late to fix now, without deleting and re-entering the question, which would tend to screw up the logic of your following comments). Also - pointing out a possible duplicate shouldn't be taken as a criticism in any way - I happened to know what to search on, while you didn't. It's just to avoid having dozens of practically identical answers cluttering the site. What's most important to me is that you get the assistance you need.

Comment: Thank you. Yea hard to say, i didnt really saw it as criticism, but also did. Often when i am searching for something, i find so many identical posts, wich makes my search hard too, so i totally can understand that cluttering here is really not good. On the other side i also read so many hatepost because of some questions, and even though some kinda "deserve" it, others dont. I am just not used to ask questions online, i guess thats why i felt i have to defend myself here a bit. This is the only site i am posting questions, and since i am a member it has only been two so far, this one included

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you don't need to join the table to itself.  If you only query it once then it will go faster.

```
SELECT user_id, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key='vorname' THEN meta_value ELSE null END) Vorname_M,
    MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key='nachname' THEN meta_value ELSE null END) Nachname_M,
    MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key='adress' THEN meta_value ELSE null END) Adresse_M
FROM wp_usermeta
GROUP BY user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

If `usermeta` is anything like `postmeta`, it has inefficient indexes.  See [*this*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta) for guidelines on improving the efficiency.

Comment: Thank you. I will have a look at it. But as far as i know indexes are better in usermeta.

Comment: @Lpion - According to [_this_](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_usermeta) the indexes on `wp_usermeta` are also sloppy.